# JS forEach traverses the problem of modifying objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach-object

Why does the first modification work (when I reassign properties of the object) but not the second (when I reassign the whole object)?

```js
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, value: 4 },
    { id: 5, value: 5 },
]

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item.value *= 10   // modify success
    }
});

console.log(arr1);

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item = {id:6,value:6}  // modify fail
    }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Note that SO is not your favourite JavaScript forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related problems. Thus, please always add the tag of the language you are using. That way the people following the JavaScript tag, will be able to find your question more easily.

Comment: Use `arr1[index] = {id:6,value:6};`

Comment: @angel.bonev This will work but OP question is that why `item = {id:6,value:6}` not working ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal So this is an example for [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the example below:

We create an object and assign it to variable `foo` and then we assign `foo` to `bar`. So, now both `foo` and `bar` refer to the same object, as illustrated in the diagram below.

```
let foo = { id: 1, val: "foo" };
let bar = foo;
```

[image]

Next let's change the `val` field of the object i.e. assigned to `bar`. We notice that the change is reflected by both the variables `foo` and `bar` and this is because both the variables refer to the same object.

```js
let foo = {id: 1,val: "foo"};
let bar = foo;
bar.val = "bar";
console.log(foo, bar);
```

[image]

Next we assign a new object to `bar`. Notice this doesn't effect the object that `foo` refers to, `bar` is simply now referring to a different object.

```js
let foo = { id: 1, val: "foo" };
let bar = foo;
bar = { id: 1, val: "bar" };
console.log(foo, bar);
```

[image]

Let's relate this to the `forEach` example in your question. So, in every iteration of the `forEach` loop, the `item` argument in the callback function points to an object from the array and when you change a field from this `item` argument it changes the object in the array but when you assign `item` to a new object it does nothing to the object stored in the array.

If you want to replace the entire object with a new one, there are several approaches you could take, two of which are mentioned below:

1. Finding the index where the object is stored and replacing it with a new object.

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, value: 1 }, { id: 2, value: 2 }, { id: 3, value: 3 }, { id: 4, value: 4 }, { id: 5, value: 5 }];

const index = arr.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === 3);
if (index !== -1) {
  arr[index] = { id: 6, value: 6 };
}

console.log(arr);
```

2. Another really common approach is to `map` over the array and create a new array with that one object replaced.

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, value: 1 }, { id: 2, value: 2 }, { id: 3, value: 3 }, { id: 4, value: 4 }, { id: 5, value: 5 }];

const newArr = arr.map((obj) => (obj.id === 3 ? { id: 6, value: 6 } : obj));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is natural, and it's to do with the difference between the actual object, and the variable.

In your foreach function, you have a variable "item" which points to the object in the array you are looping. But when you run

```
item = {id:6,value:6}
```

You are not modifying the object, but rather making the variable "item" point to a new object that you've just created.

If you want to change the actual object itself, you can do it manually by modifying the values one by one, or by copying from another object using Object.assign.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

In this snippet, I've made a few examples that hopefully illustrate the differences, and at the end your specific case being solved using Object.assign()

```js
const a = { id: 1, value: 1 };
let b = a; // b now points to the same object as variable a

b = {id: 2, value: 2};

console.log('a', a, 'b', b) // output shows two different objects with different values

const c = {id: 3, value: 3};
const d = c;
Object.assign(c, {id: 4, value: 4});
console.log('c', c, 'd', d); // c and d both have id: 4 and value: 4 because they both point to the same object

const e = { id: 5, value: 5 };
const f = e;
e.id = 6;

console.log('e', e, 'f', f); // directly assigning the value also works


const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, value: 4 },
    { id: 5, value: 5 },
]

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item.value *= 10   // modify success
    }
})

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        Object.assign(item, {id:6,value:6})  // success with assign
    }
})

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `item` is a reference to the object that's currently being iterated over, modifying the reference will in turn modify the original object (hence the behaviour observed in your first code example). In the second `forEach` you just reassign the reference to a brand new object so you can no longer modify the original object you were iterating over.

Basically, when you loop over the array with `forEach`, `item` is a variable whose current value is a reference/pointer to the object currently being iterated over. Modifying this object modifies the original (as it's just a reference, not an actual cloned object). However, when you reassign it, the reference is no longer present because `item` has a new value that it points to. You could modify it like so, with success:

```js
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, value: 4 },
    { id: 5, value: 5 },
];

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item.value *= 10   // modify success
    }
});

console.log(arr1);

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item.id = 6;
        item.value = 6;
    }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You could do it dynamically as well, by looping over each property you wish to reassign like so:

```js
const arr1 = [
    { id: 1, value: 1 },
    { id: 2, value: 2 },
    { id: 3, value: 3 },
    { id: 4, value: 4 },
    { id: 5, value: 5 },
];

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        item.value *= 10   // modify success
    }
});

console.log(arr1);

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === 1) {
        let toConvert = { id: 6, value: 6};
        Object.entries(toConvert).forEach(([k, v]) => item[k] = v);
    }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, it can be understood as:

```
const it = { value: 10 };
const item = it;
item.value = 11;
console.log(it);   // item and it point to the same object, so the object's property value is modified
```

second case:

```
const it = { value: 10 };
let item = it;           // Here item and it refer to the same object
item = { value: 6 };     // But here item points to the new object (direct assignment), and it still points to the original object
console.log(item, it);   // So it is still { value: 10 }, and item is already { value: 6 }
```